# Pythonic way to access certain parts of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array containing x (data[:,0]) and y(data[:,1]) information for a plot.

I’d like to fit a curve to the data, but only using certain parts of the data to determine the fitting parameters (e.g. using data in the range x = x1 -> x2, and x3 -> x4). My plan to do this is to create a new numpy array only containing the data I intend to pass to a SciPy CurveFitting routine.

```
index_range1 = np.where((data[:,0] > x1) and (data[:,0] < x2)
index_range2 = np.where((data[:,0] > x3) and (data[:,0] < x4)
```

and then I'd use these index ranges to pull the data of interest into a new array which I could pass to CurveFit.

Firstly, given that Python can handle complex arrays, this seems a very un-pythonic approach. Secondly, when running my script, I get an error saying that I need to use .any() or .all() in my expression for index_range 1 and 2.

I wonder, therefore, if anyone has any suggestions for an improved, more pythonic approach to solving this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a boolean array out of two others, use `&` to compare element-wise:

```
index_range1 = np.where((data[:,0] > x1) & (data[:,0] < x2))
index_range2 = np.where((data[:,0] > x3) & (data[:,0] < x4))
```

Using [boolean arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to index an array is probably more 'pythonic'.  You don't need to find (using `where`) and save the indices, you can access the data directly from the array:

```
range1 = data[(data[:,0] > x1) & (data[:,0] < x2)]
range2 = data[(data[:,0] > x3) & (data[:,0] < x4)]
```

You could shorten this/make it more readable with:

```
x, y = data.T
range1 = data[(x > x1) & (x < x2)]
range2 = data[(x > x3) & (x < x4)]
```

Note: `x` and `y` are *views*, so modifying `x`, `y` modifies `data`, and there's no copying so it shouldn't slow your code down.  But the `range`s are *copies*, since [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) makes a copy, so modifying them won't affect `x`, `y`, or `data`.

Comment: Thanks, I've combined this and the below answer to solve my problem in one line:

`my_data = data[np.logical_or(((data[:,0] > x1) & (data[:,0] < x2)),((data[:,0] > x3) & (data[:,0] < x4)))]`

Comment: @Ian You can use a pipe, `a | b` instead of `logical_or(a,b)`.

Comment: As in, `my_data = data[((data[:,0] > x1) & (data[:,0] < x2)) | ((data[:,0] > x3) & (data[:,0] < x4))]`  Use lots of parenthesis!

Comment: Thanks, that's even better!

Comment: FWIW, I think I prefer the "logical_XXX" functions to the `&` and `|` operators.  The latter actually do bitwise operations.  It turns out that they give the same results for arrays of booleans since `True` is a subclass of 1, but I find that to be a little less clear.

Comment: Good point, @mgilson, I should have warned that this only works for `dtype=bool` arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you want to use `numpy.logical_and`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.arange(100)
>>> data[np.logical_and(50 <= data,data <= 70)]
array([50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,
       67, 68, 69, 70])
```

The reason is that with regular `and`, python looks to the left array and says "Is this true-like?".  However, arrays don't have a concept of "true-like" (They refuse to guess what a "True" array would look like), so they raise the exception that you see (suggesting that maybe you meant to use the `all` or `any` methods).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the logical and function. That helps greatly.